# How to default numeric keypad in a textbox in ipod safari browser?

Tags: ipod-touch, keypad

I am working on website where I would like to display the numeric keypad in a text field.

Is it possible to default the numeric keypad once the user starts typing? Currently, the use has to click/touch the numeric symbol to get the numeric keypad.

I would really appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<input type="number">` for this. Defaults to `type="text"` for browsers not supporting it. Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)